# Cumulative average and count over occurrences increasing in time

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to calculate an average (over number of occurrences) and observation count over increasing dates per instance (take customer as an example instance) in Oracle SQL.

So the count will increase as date goes up, the average could go up or down.

I can do it for an individual case and a fixed time interval, but I would like to see a series for every customer, with every row a separate date where a sale occurred. Right now, I have a single row per customer. Here is the SQL summarizing the average and count for a fixed time interval:

```
SELECT AVG(bought_usd) as avg_bought
     , COUNT(*) as num_of_interactions
     , cust_id
FROM   salesTable
WHERE  obsdate >= DATE('2000-01-01')
AND    obsdate <= DATE('2022-01-01')
GROUP BY cust_id
```

So for an input of:

[image: input_data]

the output should look like:

[image: output_data]

Comment: Please post a data sample + required result.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution; and the expected output for that sample data.

Comment: You need to use the **analytic** versions of `avg` and `count`. You don't seem familiar with the concept (otherwise you would have thought about that on your own). Do a Google search for "analytic functions" and read about them; what you are trying to do should appear as examples in the first few pages of reading on the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT "DATE",
       cust,
       AVG(bought_usd) OVER (PARTITION BY cust ORDER BY "DATE") AS avg,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY cust ORDER BY "DATE") AS cnt
FROM   salestable
ORDER BY cust, "DATE"
```

*Note: `DATE` is a reserved word. You should not use it as an identifier.*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE salestable ("DATE", cust, bought_usd) AS
SELECT DATE '2010-10-01', 'Cust A', 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2010-12-18', 'Cust A',  50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2010-12-18', 'Cust B', 120 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2011-10-01', 'Cust B', 180 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | DATE | CUST | AVG | CNT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2010-10-01 00:00:00 | Cust A | 100 | 1 |
> | 2010-12-18 00:00:00 | Cust A | 75 | 2 |
> | 2010-12-18 00:00:00 | Cust B | 120 | 1 |
> | 2011-10-01 00:00:00 | Cust B | 150 | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1dca79eeea2851d65c4354d8b3cc6e13)*